# Using map function on array from state

Tags: reactjs

The map function isn't working when used on an array that's retrieved from the state property.

Here is how my state is defined in the class:

```
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    groups: []
  };
```

Inside my render method, I try to use the groups array like so:

```
const groups = this.state.groups;
```

Inside of my return statement in the render method, I call `groups.map()`

However, I get an error saying that map() is an invalid function for groups.

However, when I set the groups array outside of state entirely like so:

```
   let groups = [];
   groups = this.state.groups;
```

The map function works just fine. So it seems that `this.state.groups` isn't actually accessing the groups array in state. How can I access the array from state?

Here is my full file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    groups: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    //const response = await fetch('/api/groups');
    //const body = await response.json();
    const testJson = '{"id" : "1", "name" : "Denver"}';
    const body = JSON.parse(testJson);
    this.setState({ groups: body, isLoading: false });
  }

  render() {
    const {groups, isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <div className="App-intro">
            <h2>JUG List</h2>
            {groups.map(group =>
              <div key={group.id}>
                {group.name}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test json is parsed into an object, which you can't `map` over (at least, not without a third-party library to provide a `map` that works for objects, like `lodash`'s `_.map`). If you change that to `const testJson = '[{"id" : "1", "name" : "Denver"}]'` it should work.